# C++ simple program realization

Tags: c++

I need your help to get started with a good implementation thinking.

I need to create a simple program with the following:
1. A function with two parameters, first parameter is a name (char*), and the second parameter is the number of times you would like to print this name to the screen(int).
If the second parameter wasn't supplied in the function call, it should print the name 10 times.
If the first parameter wasn't supplied in the function call, it should print the author name / the writer of the program (i.e my name).

I was thinking to create the following function with default parameteres:

```
void printTextToScreenNTimes(char * text = "guy", int n = 10);
```

This function implementation is the following :

```
void printTextToScreenNTimes(char * text, int n) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << text << " ";

}
```

My problem arises as I try to print my default name 2 times. For example if I want only using the following function call:

```
void printTextToScreenNTimes(3);
```

I would like the function to print the default name (in this case "guy") 3 times but It's impossible because I must fill the first parameter.

Do I have no choice but using a global parameter holding my name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading:

```
void printTextToScreenNTimes(int x)
{
    printTextToScreeNTimes("guy", x);
}
```

Comment: I'm using this code your provided but I want to change "Guy" into a const varaible.

Can you please help me understand what the different between the following implementation ( all work fine) :

    char * const AUTHOR_NAME = "GUY";

    static char * AUTHOR_NAME = "GUY";

    char * AUTHOR_NAME = "GUY";


All these are above the main.

For some reason the following line didn't work for me : 

    char * const AUTHOR_NAME = "GUY";

Thaks,
Guy

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried to do so but I'm a new user so I have to wait 8 hours atleast before answering. I can only add comments.

Comment: @Guy okay, can you post the code on http://www.ideone.com and add comments to what you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks man.. Here it is :http://ideone.com/Jkk9wl I wrote there what I don't understand.

Comment: @Guy see http://ideone.com/X5eGm0 also, what do you mean the last one doesn't work. It's identical to the first, which does.

Comment: I may didn't explain myself correctly. I would like to understand what the differences between all these four defintions. when you add static for example. the first one and the last one are different because when I call a function with this varaible the first one allows me to preform the call and the second doesn't. Oh I'm sorry... the last one is : const * char.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading too much into your requirements. I think the second part about not supplying the name only applies when the first part (not supplying the count) also applies.

But in any case you can solve it using overloading as Luchian has just explained.